# Ayuda con consulta mysql con diferentes condicionales if php

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones

Necesito realizar una consulta mysql con condicionales if desde php. La idea es hacer pasar la variable consulta, por el where del consulta para no estar haciendo una diferente por cada vez que se consulte.
Estas son las condiciones php:

```
$WHERE = "";

if ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin == "" && $clinica = ""){
    $WHERE.="  pedidos.lab = '.$id_us.' AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido = '.$fecha_in.' ";

}elseif ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin != "" && $clinica = ""){
    $WHERE.=" pedidos.lab = '.$id_us.' AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido BETWEEN '.$fecha_in.' AND '.$fecha_fin.' ";

}elseif ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin != "" && $clinica != ""){
    $WHERE.=" pedidos.lab = '.$id_us.' AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido BETWEEN '.$fecha_in.' AND '.$fecha_fin.' AND pedidos.cliente = '.$clinica.' ";

}elseif ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin == "" && $clinica != ""){
    $WHERE.=" pedidos.lab = '.$id_us.' AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido = '.$fecha_in.' AND pedidos.cliente = '.$clinica.' " ;
}
```

Obviamente las fechas ya estan formateadas y con su correspondiente formato.
Lo que necesito es meter ese $WHERE en el WHERE de mi consulta para realice las condiciones segun los datos que lleguen.
Mi consulta es:

```
$consulta = "

SELECT distinct
  pedidos.id,
  pedidos.correlativo,
  pedidos.nombres,
  pedidos.apellidos,
  pedidos.cliente,
  pedidos.tratamiento,
  clientes.nombre AS cliente,
  hijos.opcion AS tratamiento,
  asignacion.estado_entrega,
  asignacion.estado_envio,
    asignacion.fecha_envio,
    asignacion.fecha_cierre AS cierre,
  pedidos.estado,
  pedidos.asignado,
  pedidos.estado_recep,
    pedidos.fecha_entrega AS tope
FROM
  pedidos

  INNER JOIN clientes ON (clientes.id = pedidos.cliente)
  INNER JOIN hijos ON (hijos.id = pedidos.tratamiento)
  LEFT JOIN asignacion ON (pedidos.id = asignacion.id_pedido)

WHERE ".$WHERE." ";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
        $arreglo["data"][]= $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);

}else{
    echo '{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": "0",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "0",
    "aaData": []
    }';
}
```

Si alguien tuviera alguna solucion o me diga que puedo hacer se lo agradeceria muchisimo. Cabe destacar, que el resultado de esta consulta, se va por json a un archivo que lo estructura a traves de datatables.
Agradecido como siempre por su ayuda.
saludos.

Comment: Prueba quitando los puntos de los Where  `'.$id_us.'` quedando así `'$id_us'` y bueno normalmente las comillas simples `'` son requeridas es para los campos de fecha.

Comment: @CesarRomero ya habia hecho eso antes, con las variables fechas y las otras pero la query no muestra resultados ni tampoco error. La consola tampoco muestra registros de error.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes al hacerle un `echo` a tu variable `$consulta`?

Comment: @FernandoUrban, gracias por tu pregunta. Me imprime la consulta mysql antes mencionada con la variable fecha que corresponda. Hice tambien una comprobacion a las condicionales if y estan funcionando. el tema al parecer es la llamada a la variable $WHERE, ya que cuando envio una fecha, 2 fechas o mas datos, es como si no la tomara en cuenta y muestra todos los registros de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

es sencillo.

Voy a tomar tu mismo ejemplo y voy a simplificar u organizar de forma distinta.

Uso la variable `$WHERE` como un Array para ir agregando elementos al **WHERE** del SQL.

```
$WHERE = array();
$WHERE[] = "pedidos.asignado = 'S'";
$WHERE[] = "pedidos.tipo_trat = 1";
$WHERE[] = "pedidos.lab = " . (int) $id_us;
$WHERE[] = "pedidos.estado_recep = 'N'";

if ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin == "" && $clinica = ""){
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.fecha_pedido = '" . $fecha_in . "'";
} else if ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin != "" && $clinica = ""){
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.fecha_pedido BETWEEN '" . $fecha_in . "' AND '" . $fecha_fin . "'";

} else if ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin != "" && $clinica != ""){
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.fecha_pedido BETWEEN '" . $fecha_in . "' AND '" . $fecha_fin . "'";
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.cliente = '" . $clinica . "'";
} else if ($fecha_in !="" && $fecha_fin == "" && $clinica != ""){
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.fecha_pedido = '" . $fecha_in . "'" ;
    $WHERE[] = "pedidos.cliente = '" . $clinica . "'";
}


$consulta = "

SELECT distinct
  pedidos.id,
  pedidos.correlativo,
  pedidos.nombres,
  pedidos.apellidos,
  pedidos.cliente,
  pedidos.tratamiento,
  clientes.nombre AS cliente,
  hijos.opcion AS tratamiento,
  asignacion.estado_entrega,
  asignacion.estado_envio,
  asignacion.fecha_envio,
  asignacion.fecha_cierre AS cierre,
  pedidos.estado,
  pedidos.asignado,
  pedidos.estado_recep,
    pedidos.fecha_entrega AS tope
FROM
  pedidos
INNER JOIN 
  clientes ON (clientes.id = pedidos.cliente)
INNER JOIN 
  hijos ON (hijos.id = pedidos.tratamiento)
LEFT JOIN 
  asignacion ON (pedidos.id = asignacion.id_pedido) 
" . (count($WHERE) > 0 ? "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $WHERE) : "");
```

Si en algún caso necesitas que la consulta SQL quede sin condiciones *"(sin WHERE)"*, puedes condicionar las 4 líneas siguientes a la declaración del Array.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, realizare las pruebas ahora y le comento como me va. Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: He realizado las pruebas, pero sigue sin mostrar los resultados esperados. Si bien, ahora muestras los registros, no filtra por fechas ni rangos de fechas, pero si muestra los registros filtrados por las otras condiciones iniciales. Tendra algo que ver, el como se devuelven los datos? Porque son enviados por JSON . Saludos.

Comment: Como están llegando los datos de: `$fecha_in, fecha_fin, $clinica`?

Comment: Estan llegado en formato dd-mm-yyyy a traves de datepicker. Para hacer las consultas, las transformo a formato yyyy-mm-dd, ya que ese es el formato que tiene la BD. Al imprimir las fechas, estas se imprimen en formato correcto.

Comment: Ese es el problema. Cámbiale el formato a Y-m-d.
Ejemplo: 2018-12-19.

Comment: Que tipo de dato le tienes configurado a la columna **fecha_pedido**

Comment: tiene formato date. Pregunta. Si las fechas llegan en formato dd-mm-yyyy y luego se transforman a yyyy-mm-dd para hacer las consultas, porque deberia estar ahi el error? saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En los where creo que te faltan agregar unas comillas dobles al insertar las variables así:

```
  $WHERE.="  pedidos.lab = '".$id_us."' AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido = '".$fecha_in."' ";
```

también verifica ya que en sql las variables numéricas no llevan comillas y podría se así asumiendo que pedidos.lab es numérico

```
$WHERE.="  pedidos.lab = ".$id_us." AND pedidos.tipo_trat = 1 AND pedidos.asignado = 'S' AND pedidos.estado_recep = 'N' AND pedidos.fecha_pedido = '".$fecha_in."' ";
```